# docker - can i set up a container to be accessed directly through ssh from the network?

Tags: docker, networking

i have an application that i run on a powerful computer on the network. the basic idea is that a user clicks something, then a task is sent to the remote computer trough ssh, executes some commands, then returns something. it is pretty straight forward.

however, the computer is shared by other users, so i decided i want to isolate my application in a docker container. What i would ideally want is that instead of ssh to the remote computer, you just ssh to the docker. i though this is pretty easy, but its giving me some trouble. How would i go about this?

Comment: Anything that involves ssh as a core transport turns out to be kind of complicated: you need a user and credentials to exist on both the client and the server side, and this is hard to set up securely, especially in Docker.  Can you use a job queue like RabbitMQ instead?

Comment: (Remember the first rule of Docker security: anyone who can run any `docker` command can [pretty easily root the entire host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface).  If you have a multi-user system, allowing users to `docker run` applications will probably make it less secure, if you don't already give them `sudo` access.)